# AWS Batch permits approx 25 concurrent jobs in array configuration while compute environment allows using 256 CPU

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate, aws-batch

I am running Job Array on the AWS Batch using Fargate Spot environment.
The main goal is to do some work as quickly as possible. So, when I run 100 jobs I expect that all of these jobs will be run simultaneously.
But only approx 25 of them start immediately, the rest of jobs are waiting with RUNNABLE status.

The jobs run on compute environment with max. 256 CPU. Each job uses 1 CPU or even less.

I haven't found any limits or quotas that can influence the process of running jobs.

What could be the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've talked with AWS Support and they advised me not to use Fargate when I need to process a lot of jobs as quick as possible.
For large-scale job processing, On-Demand solution is recommended.

So, after changed Provisioning model to On-Demand number of concurrent jobs grown up to CPU limits determined in settings, this was what I needed.